Continuous output current limits on logic families
I noticed a lot of 5V logic families (HCT, LV, etc) specify only a maximum continuous output current but not a peak:

Source:  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lv1t34.pdf
They'll often also specify output voltage/currents corresponding to tens of Ohms, meaning they can be used to drive cables. For example, the above part specs .55V rise sinking 12 mA, suggesting < 50 Ohm output impedance.   Thus if you add a series resistor to source terminate to a 50 ohm cable, the current supplied will be 5V/(50+50) = 50 mA, double the absolute max, although not continuously.
I see a lot of these families used to drive cables, so I'm assuming it is ok to transiently exceed the continuous max, but how should that "continuous" limit be interpreted?  This Toshiba document suggests that loads of up to 500 pF can be directly connected to logic gates, which might be 5-8x the absolute max for ~10 ns, which seems like a lot.  Is this limit just thermal, so huge current is ok so long as the device is allowed to dissipate heat?  Or is there some other background knowledge I'm missing?
Goal is to design reliable line and capacitive load drivers for timing/synchronization applications.

There are other failure modes besides thermal such as electromigration.
Unless you're interested in exploring what goes on within jellybean chips in detail, it might be better to use properly characterized drivers or limit the current with a resistor.
Remember the definition of "Absolute Maximum" specifically tells you that operating at or near those levels may adversely affect reliability. From your link, emphasis added:

Stresses beyond those listed under Absolute Maximum Ratings may cause
permanent damage to the device. These are stress ratings only, and
functional operation of the device at these or any other conditions
beyond those indicated under Recommended Operating Conditions is not
implied. Exposure to absolute-maximum-rated conditions for extended
periods may affect device reliability.

This is typically especially important if your application requires reliability and operates at high temperatures, since almost everything bad happens a lot faster when things are warm.

Is there a logic family that is well characterized?  I've seen line driver ICs that obviously are speced for this, but I was surprised how few of the parts I see recommended here and elsewhere that actually specify how much current they can safely switch into a transmission line.

@user1850479:  Most logic ICs are intended to drive other members of the same logic family, unless specifically described as line drivers or other special-purpose types.

74HC devices are designed and characterized to at least sink significant current (driving 74LS inputs) so that might be an option. I see +/- 4mA specified.  LVDS devices are designed to drive a transmission line.
